# How to load jar file in Java project as a dependency programatically

Tags: java, spring, runtime, classpath

In jar:

```
Class A {getter setter}
```

In war:(load above jar runtime)

```
Class B {A a=new A()}
```

Problem :

Now the actual problem was when I deploy the war without adding that jar dependency (in pom), but want to pick that jar from some local `sys` folder when I deploy that war.

I tried `URLClassLoader`, problem here is I am able to load all the classes from jar, but still `Class A` is unable to resolve.

Comment: Try to google first. Possible duplicate of [How should I load Jars dynamically at runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60764/how-should-i-load-jars-dynamically-at-runtime)

Comment: Yah thanks kirill, tried all even the first approach works nicely which I googled the same, but when I build tat war first it's getting failed... But I can able to get the class which am looking for. But when I deploy into tomcat it should execute one class loader which I wrote and add that jar as a dependency for my war?? Tats a doubt –

Comment: Add the jar that contains Class A as a dependency to your war's pom file, but add it as `<scope>provided</scope>` so it doesn't get bundled and in the way of your `sys` folder loading.

Comment: Yep...  Tats the Usual way heenenee...in tat case I need to put tat jar as a dependency in Pom... I don't want tat...as simple we can say need to do the same Pom logic in Java class..  How.???